# How I can escape from using sessions in Django?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

### What I'm trying to do?

I want to display 2 registration forms separately of each other on the same page. The forms are: built-in `User` model and my self created `UserProfile`. To track, on what form user is now, I use `sessions`. It some sort of flags for me at the moment.

### Why I don't want to use sessions?

I discovered a 'bug', at least for me, that I don't know how to fix. Bug appears if user passed first registration form, and close browser/tab. Next time user opens registration page, it will show second registration form, instead of first, as expected.

---

### Where bug happens, but now with code.

When user opens register page first time, built-in `UserCreationForm` will be show, because there is no session called `username` yet.

```
def get(self, request):
    if request.session.get("username", None):
        self.context["form"] = RegisterProfile()
    else:
        self.context["form"] = UserCreationForm()
```

I'm using `CBV`, so it's OK that function called `get` and first argument is `self`. Also I created `context` dictionary as instance variable, so I can just add new field `form` to it.

Next, if user fill in given form (note, that first form is built-in User's form) built-in `User` instance will be created and it's `username` will be stored in `username` session.
If you confused at the moment don't worry much, I leave full `view` code at the bottom.

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    request.session["username"] = request.POST["username"]
    return redirect("register")
```

Now, when session `username` exsists, and user redirected to same view, my self-created form will be shown. As in first code example.

---

Now, bug happens. User can freely leave page, and when he come back, second registration form will be shown again. That's not what I want.

Full view code:

```
class Register(View):
    context = {"title": "Register new account"}

    def get(self, request):
        if request.session.get("username", None):
            self.context["form"] = RegisterProfile()
        else:
            self.context["form"] = UserCreationForm()

        return render(request, "users/register.html", context=self.context)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.session.get("username", None):
            form = RegisterProfile(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = request.session.get("username", None)
                if not username:
                    messages.error(request, "We are sorry, but error happend. Try again!")
                    return redirect("index")

                user = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()

                profile = UserProfile(
                    user=user,
                    nickname=request.POST["nickname"],
                    sex=request.POST["sex"],
                    age=request.POST["age"],
                    profile_picture=form.files["profile_picture"],
                )
                profile.save()

                del request.session["username"]
                messages.success(request, "Profile created successfully!")
                return redirect("index")
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                request.session["username"] = request.POST["username"]
                return redirect("register")

        self.context["form"] = form
        return render(request, "users/register.html", context=self.context)
```

---

UPD 1:

I changed register logic a little, now full code looks like this:

```
class Register(View):
    context = {"title": "Register user page"}


    def get(self, request):
        if request.session.get("user_data", None):
            form = ProfileRegisterForm()
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        self.context["form"] = form
        return render(request, "users/register.html", context=self.context)


    def post(self, request):
        if request.session.get("user_data", None):
            form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = User.objects.create_user(*request.session["user_data"])
                user.save()

                UserProfile.objects.create(
                    user=user,
                    nickname=request.POST["nickname"],
                    sex=request.POST["sex"],
                    age=request.POST["age"],
                    profile_picture=form.files["profile_picture"],
                )

                del request.session["user_data"]
                messages.success(request, "Profile created successfully!")
                return redirect("index")
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                request.session["user_data"] = [
                    request.POST["username"],
                    request.POST["password1"],
                    request.POST["password2"]
                ]
                return redirect("register")
        self.context["form"] = form
        return redirect("register")
```

But anyway, I need place to store temporary data like `username`, `password1` and `password2`. If someone knows, where I can store data like in sessions, please, answer bellow.

Comment: Sessions expire at some point, they are deleted or they change for whatever reason. You need to change your approach and login the user after he or she registers or whatever UserCreation means, refresh the session after login and then control what form to show by checking request.user.is_authenticated(). And change the register page to some sort of login/register page where users can either login or register.

Comment: @Borut login logic is not ready yet, currently I'm thinking how to solve this weird thing, or how I should build 2-step register logic.

Comment: I'd probably build a 2-step register logic or not create the user until the register process is completed. The advantage of the 2-step logic is that a user does not need to complete the profile upon registering and can do that at a later time. The advantage of not creating user until the entire process is completed is that you don't end up with gazilion "ghost" users that change their mind after basic registration.

Comment: @Borut yeah, I understand this too now. probably, I should rebuild my logic. but anyway, I still open for any suggestions.